# WSO2 API Manager with F5

Tags: wso2, load-balancing, wso2-api-manager, f5

We are trying to setup WSO2 API manager cluster with F5 as the load balancer and been having issues with having F5 in the mix. One manager instance is setup on a server (server/Admin port: node1.xyz.com:9443) with F5 (manager.xyz.com that maps to node1.xyz.com:9443).

After several trial and error methods, we found the issue to be with API key manager URL configuration in the worker instance. Using direct server/port URL (i.e. node1.xyz.com:9443) works fine. However, when we use the F5 url (i.e. manager.xyz.com) results in the exception below. Any thoughts as to what may be incorrect or missing?

Eventually we want to have two manager instances running. So, we like to get this F5 setup working such that worker instances can point to F5 instead of individual manager node.

Thanks for the help in advance!

**Configuration in the Worker node that works:**

```
<APIKeyManager>
        <!--
            Server URL of the API key manager
        -->
<ServerURL>https://node1.xyz.com:9443${carbon.context}/services/</ServerURL>
```

**Configuration in the Worker node that causes error with F5:**

```
<APIKeyManager>
        <!--
            Server URL of the API key manager
        -->
<ServerURL>https://manager.xyz.com${carbon.context}/services/</ServerURL>
```

**Exception when using F5:**

```
TID: [0] [AM] [2014-12-11 16:03:37,697] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.APIAuthenticationHandler} -  API authentication failure {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.APIAuthenticationHandler}
org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.APISecurityException: Error while accessing backend services for API key validation
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.thrift.ThriftAPIDataStore.getAllURITemplates(ThriftAPIDataStore.java:99)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.APIKeyValidator.getAllURITemplates(APIKeyValidator.java:516)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.APIKeyValidator.doGetAPIInfo(APIKeyValidator.java:368)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.APIKeyValidator.findMatchingVerb(APIKeyValidator.java:343)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.APIKeyValidator.getResourceAuthenticationScheme(APIKeyValidator.java:172)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.oauth.OAuthAuthenticator.authenticate(OAuthAuthenticator.java:93)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.APIAuthenticationHandler.handleRequest(APIAuthenticationHandler.java:92)
```

Answer (score 1):

Few immediate things you could check -

- Make sure the `<HostName>` and `<MgtHostName>` elements in `KeyManager_HOME/repository/conf/carbon.xml` are set to the hostname of the F5. ie. "manager.xyz.com"
- Add the `proxyPort=443` attribute to the https connector in `KeyManager_HOME/repository/conf/tomcat/catalina-server.xml`. Configure http connector as well if desired.

If you did not set above two settings, then the http 302 redirects fail which might explain your scenario. And, we ask users to configure ProxyPassReverse in addition to ProxyPass when using Apache HTTPD as the reverse proxy. I'm not sure the equivalent config for F5.

---

If the above didn't help we need to know how your deployment looks like to better help you. ie. how do you cluster the nodes. Do you have separate API gateway, keymanager instances etc.

I think it will worth your while to go through the [WSO2 cluster guide](https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER420/Clustering+API+Manager) to understand the clustering logic better.

With APIM, you can have separate Keymanager, API gateway (and API store, API publisher) nodes. **The worker-manager separation only applies to the API Gateway.** And, **There is no worker-manager separation needed for the keymanager.** So, you may think the all the API keymanager nodes are hybrid nodes that provide both manager and worker functionality.

We can see further if you do not have separate keymanagers.

Comment: Thanks Kasun. Key manager is running as part of store and publisher. So, there are no distributed deployments involved. MgtHost and tomcat proxy ports are configured per your highlights/API cluster guide. I see newer version of API Manager 1.8 and the clustering documentation is much better with that version. Will retry with a clean install and let you know how it goes. To give little bit of context on how we are configuring F5, we want all port 9443 (ELB) traffics to be routed to one F5/DNS name and the NIO port traffic to be routed to another F5/DNS name.

Comment: One question though - Is ELB that comes with APIM required or can F5 take on that role?

Comment: -The clean setup with 1.8 version seems to work with the exception of following: (1)The revoke URL in apimanager.xml had to be the local IP instead of F5 for token renewals. (2)Adding new APIs had to be manually synced to other nodes (the files under synapse-configs/default/api).Is there a way to sync this automatically? (3)APIM appends the port # (e.g. 9443) when the default context root is used through F5 (although tomcat proxy port is configured). If F5 is manager.xyz.com,then manager.xyz.com/publisher works fine. However,manager.xyz.com/ redirects to manager.xyz.com:9443/publisher

Comment: Let me try to answer the questions as I see. 

2) You need to use deployment synchronizer to sync the apis across the nodes. There's a separate page on cluster guide for this. 

3) This is interesting. I just tested this w/ apache httpd, and it seems to work fine for me. I hope that you have set proxyPort for both the connectors in catalina-server.xml.

Comment: If you already have a load balancer, you can go ahead with that. You do not need to bring the ELB into the picture.